# How to select elements of the list substring of the field value in Jinja?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

There is a jinja selectattr expression:

```
{{ foo|selectattr("name", "equalto", "bar42")|list }}
```

Now I want to filter based on fact that there is '42' in the name. Python version would be `[x for x in foo if '42' in x['name']]` What kind of operator should I use? `in` is not suited because it doing it in reverse, testing if `name` in in the sequence I provided.

I need to do the opposite: to check if my substring is in the name.

Answer (score 0):

I found two important details:

1. It's called 'test', not 'filter', and there is a whole page dedicated to ansible-specific tests for jinja: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html
2. There is a set of three tests for strings: `match`, `search` and `regex`.

My problem was solved by 'search' test:

```
{{ foo|selectattr("name", "search", "42")|list }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*Filter based on fact that there is '42' in the name.*"**

A: In addition to the [Jinja tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) you can use [Ansible tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html), i.e. [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) in this particular case, e.g. given the list

```yaml
    foo:
      - name: foo42
      - name: bar42
      - name: baz99
```

Search the regex '42' in the names

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|selectattr('name', 'search', '42')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - name: foo42
  - name: bar42
```

---

For your convenience. See the test file below.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo:
      - name: foo42
      - name: bar42
      - name: baz99
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|selectattr('name', 'equalto', 'bar42')|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|selectattr('name', 'match', 'bar42')|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|selectattr('name', 'match', '42')|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|selectattr('name', 'search', '42')|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|selectattr('name', 'regex', '42')|list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for repeating my own answer.

Comment: Great minds think alike :). Your answer had not been here when I started. I posted the answer 10 minutes after you. To add new value I posted the test file.